# Objective-C: How to check if date occurred between two dates?

Tags: objective-c, date, compare, nsdate

I searched this question before and found:

```
if (([dateToCompare compare:4HoursEarlier] == NSOrderedAscending) && ([dateToCompare compare:specifiedDate] == NSOrderedDescending))
{
    NSLog(@"dateToCompare between 4HoursEarlier and specifiedDate");
    // do something
}
```

Unfortunately, this seems not to work (the NSLog never gets printed).

I have a for loop that goes through an array (which contains dates). I need to check if the specified date is within 4 hours of another date. I have (pseudocode):

```
specifiedDate = a date I specify;
dateToCompare = current date gathered in for loop;
4HoursEarlier = 4 hours before specifiedDate;
```

How can I check if a specifiedDate is within 4 hours of dateToCompare (a date gathered from an array/for loop)?

Comment: 1) Not an answer, but I finally broke down and created an NSDate category with `isBefore:` and `isAfter:` methods, since the NSOrdered stuff is too hard to keep straight.  2) Have you double-checked that 4hoursEarlier is really that.  3) How do you create a variable named "4hoursEarlier"?

Comment: NSDate *4HoursEarlier = [specifiedDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-3600*4]; I NSLog it and it also appears to be 4 hours earlier.

Comment: @HotLicks I just figured out I should be able to do a simple greater than statement and not have to deal with compare.

Comment: @HotLicks: NSDate already has earlierDate: and laterDate:.

Comment: @MartinR - earlierDate and laterDate don't return BOOLs.

Comment: @Shane - Using '>' and '<' may appear to work, but that's really just comparing addresses, and if it works it's purely accidental.  You can, if you wish, use `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` and compare those values.

Comment: @HotLicks: Oops, yes ... sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got the comparisons the wrong way around.  Exchange  `NSOrderedAscending` and `NSOrderedDescending` in your condition.

My memory aid is

```
[obj1 compare:obj2] == NSOrderedAscending  : obj1, obj2 is an ascending sequence
[obj1 compare:obj2] == NSOrderedDescending : obj1, obj2 is an descending sequence
```

Therefore, to check if `dateToCompare` is later in time than `fourHoursEarlier`, you have
to use

```
if ([dateToCompare compare:fourHoursEarlier] == NSOrderedDescending) ...
```

Comment: Replace ascending with descending and visa versa?

Comment: Like I said, the NSOrdered stuff is hard to keep straight.